# How to get the single images of an mp4-Movie in Java

Tags: java, decode, mp4

I want to do some image analysis on a video that's stored in .mp4 format. Therefore I need a way to just get the images of this movie in Java.
I goolged a lot and found some libraries like jcodec and jaad. BUT I wasn't able to get the things running with these libraries. And as I found out, there were examples (at least I found none) that showed my usecase.

Can you help me? Do you know any library that can do what I need and is running at least on Win7 64 bit. 
Or do you know how to accomplish this with jcodec?

edit:

As I wrote, I tried it with jcodec. I found out how to get the data of a frame, but not how I can get it into something like a BufferedImage or so. I expect that these data isn't in a simple RGB format but in any compressed format or so. (Am I right with that?) I don't know to to decode this data.

You can get the data of a frame with jcodec as follows (at least as far as I understand this):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, MP4DemuxerException {
    String path = "videos/video-2011-09-21-20-07-21.mp4";

    MP4Demuxer demuxer1 = new MP4Demuxer(new FileInput(new File(path)));
    DemuxerTrack videoTrack = demuxer1.getVideoTrack();

    Packet firstFrame = videoTrack.getFrames(1);
    byte[] data = firstFrame.getData();
}
```

I also found the following:
http://code.google.com/p/jcodec/source/browse/trunk/src/test/java/org/jcodec/containers/mp4/DitherTest.java?r=70
But this isn't working (has compile errors) with the downloadable jar-package.

Comment: Can anyone help on my updated question?

Answer (score 6):

you could use jcodec(https://github.com/jcodec/jcodec) in the followinf program i am extracting frames from a video.

```
/*
 * To extract frames from a mp4(avc) video
 * 
 */
package avc_frame;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.jcodec.api.FrameGrab;
import org.jcodec.api.JCodecException;

public class Avc_frame {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JCodecException {
  
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 50; i < 57; i++) { 
            BufferedImage frame = FrameGrab.getFrame(new File("/Users/jovi/Movies/test.mp4"), i);
            ImageIO.write(frame, "bmp", new File("/Users/jovi/Desktop/frames/frame_"+i+".bmp"));
        }
        System.out.println("Time Used:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time)+" Milliseconds");
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use this code I get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Could someone check my stack trace? http://pastebin.com/YQVVH559

Comment: What IDE are you using?,I used Netbeans and then imported the jcodec library (External JAR/Library import option). After import it should work.

Comment: Also take care of the for loop, in the example above the video had more than 57 frames. So it was safe to assume that for loop. Modify for your use case.

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.FrameGrabber.Exception;

public class Read{
    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException, Exception
    {
        FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("C:/Users/Digilog/Downloads/Test.mp4");
        frameGrabber.start();
        IplImage i;
        try {

            i = frameGrabber.grab();
            BufferedImage  bi = i.getBufferedImage();
            ImageIO.write(bi,"png", new File("D:/Img.png"));
            frameGrabber.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: This Program will give you 1st frame of  mp4 video.

Comment: It will also work however if You only need to get single frame from video file it's much better to go with solution using jcodec library. It's lightweight and weight about 2MB, however using javacv You will need to import about 400MB because it internally uses OpenCV.