# How to extract programmatically video frames?

Tags: java, python, haskell, erlang, video-processing

I need programmatically extract frames from mp4 video file, so each frame goes into a separate file. Please advise on a library that will allow to get result similar to the following VLC command (http://www.videolan.org/vlc/):

```
vlc v1.mp4 --video-filter=scene --vout=dummy --start-time=1 --stop-time=5 --scene-ratio=1 --scene-prefix=img- --scene-path=./images vlc://quit
```

Library for any of these Java / Python / Erlang / Haskell will do the job for me.

Comment: An answer that I just posted here will be useful for anyone else who wants to do a similar thing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22107132/398316

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally look for libraries that wrap ffmpeg/libavcodec (the understands-most-things library that many encoders and players use).

I've not really tried any yet so can't say anything about code quality and ease, but [the five-line pyffmpeg example](https://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/#Example) suggests it's an easy option - though it may well be *nix-only.

Comment: This is currently outdated

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the following [class](http://popscan.blogspot.fr/2012/08/reading-and-processing-video-frames.html) by Popscan. The usage is as follows:

```
VideoSource vs = new VideoSource("file://c:\test.avi");
vs.initialize();
...
int frameIndex = 12345; // any frame 
BufferedImage frame = vs.getFrame(frameIndex);
```

Comment: VideoSource requires JMF. Source and docs available here, but it's too old to be useful: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html