# Java Frame Grabber

Tags: java, video, frame

can anyone give me a hint on how to get a frame from an mp4 video, by providing a timestamp (in ms or so)?

I'm trying to seek a video frame by frame.

Thanks,
Pateta

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735716/how-can-i-get-a-frame-sample-jpeg-from-a-video-mov

Comment: Thank you. It helped me out. I started using JavaCV and it works well.